# Async call for delegate in cycle

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, delegates

I need to call asynchronously number of delegates for the same function.
The question is how i should treat the call back function ?
we have couple of delegates running so CallbackMethod doesn't mean that that all async delegates finished.

```
AsyncMethodCaller c = new AsyncMethodCaller(instance.dummyMethod);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        IAsyncResult res = c.BeginInvoke(5000,
            out dummy, 
            new AsyncCallback(CallbackMethod),
            "executed on thread {0}, with result value \"{1}\".");
}
```

Comment: CallbackMethod will be called for each invocation of instance.dummyMethod. If you need to wait till all invocations are complete in your main thread, you can add all of the IAsyncResult's to a list and then poll each item in the loop by calling IAsyncResult.IsComplete or use WaitHandle.WaitAll method

Answer (score 0):

I would consider looking at using `Task`s provided with [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
var task1 = Task.Run(() => instance.dummyMethod)
   .ContinueWith((completedTask) => Console.WriteLine("Each callback here. Result: " + completedTask.Result));

// Blocks calling thread until all tasks are done.
Task.WaitAll(new [] { task1, task2 });
```

The `WaitAll` all ensures that all `Task`s are done before continuing on the main thread. The above allows you to implement individual callbacks.

Alternatively use a *single callback* when **All** the async methods are complete:

```
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new [] { task1, task2 },
   (allTasks) => Console.WriteLine("Callback when all are done."));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-Main") for this as it would be so much simpler.

Here's the code:

```
var query =
    from n in Observable.Range(0, 100)
    from dummy in Observable.Start(() => instance.dummyMethod())
    select dummy;

query
    .Subscribe(
        dummy =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dummy.ToString());
        },
        () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        });
```

The `.Subscribe` method has a callback for each `dummy` value produced as well as a "done" callback when all the values have been returned.

The query runs on multiple threads automatically for you.